# GSON - convert a string into a JsonArray

Tags: java, json, gson, kotlin

I am trying to convert a string into a JsonArray. So far I have tried to do the following:

`Gson().toJson(string)`

`Gson().toJsonTree(string)`

both throw an exception saying that the argument is not a JsonArray.

Here is the string, as you can see it is a JsonArray:

```
"[{\"match\":{\"id\":92757102,\"tournament_id\":3666234,\"state\":\"open\",\"player1_id\":58602461,\"player2_id\":58602459,\"player1_prereq_match_id\":null,\"player2_prereq_match_id\":null,\"player1_is_prereq_match_loser\":false,\"player2_is_prereq_match_loser\":false,\"winner_id\":null,\"loser_id\":null,\"started_at\":\"2017-07-17T19:10:07.588-04:00\",\"created_at\":\"2017-07-17T19:10:07.476-04:00\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-07-17T19:10:07.588-04:00\",\"identifier\":\"A\",\"has_attachment\":false,\"round\":1,\"player1_votes\":null,\"player2_votes\":null,\"group_id\":null,\"attachment_count\":null,\"scheduled_time\":null,\"location\":null,\"underway_at\":null,\"optional\":false,\"rushb_id\":null,\"completed_at\":null,\"suggested_play_order\":1,\"prerequisite_match_ids_csv\":\"\",\"scores_csv\":\"\"}}]"
```

Comment: `new Gson().fromJson(string)` ?

Comment: That's not a JSON array. That's a JSON string. You re-encoded the JSON array.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Gson().fromJson(string, JsonArray::class.java)`

Comment: Please have a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer to provide more detail. Specifically, it would be helpful if you explained how this solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonArray data = (JsonArray) JsonParser.parseString(str);
```

Answer (score -1):

`toJson()` renders a json object as a string (of json).

You want the `fromJson()` method, which converts a string to a json object.

Try:

```
new Gson().fromJson(string, JsonArray.class)
```

Comment: That wouldn't throw an exception. They must have mistyped.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis There is no exception. OP is confusing "throwing an exception" with "compiler error".

Comment: Maybe. Your suggested code still has compilation errors though.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis right. I was too quick there. How about now.

Comment: Yeah, that would compile but would fail to parse the string in their question.