# How to convert String values into LatLng() objects?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have latlng values in String .I want to convert That String into LatLng objects. like`LatLng latlng = new LatLng(lat, lng);`

This is my data :

```
String latlan =" 
    [[13.041695199971244, 77.61311285197735], 
    [13.042000923637021, 77.61313531547785], 
    [13.041830750574812, 77.61335827410221], 
    [13.041507062142946, 77.61269208043814]]
";
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to parse the string which is in JSON format.

Comment: this data is not a JSON format.it is String.

Comment: i want to add this string into LatLan..like LatLan latlan = new LatLan(string);

Comment: What is `LatLan`? probably you mean `LatLng`?

Comment: You need to parse the `latlan` String into a JsonArray and then iterate through them. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155067/gson-convert-a-string-into-a-jsonarray)

Comment: yes,That is LatLng()

Comment: It is indeed JSON format. Not sure why you think it is not

Comment: thanks buddy for your help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Parse your data as follows:

```
List<LatLng> coordinates = new ArrayList<>();
try {
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(latlan);
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONArray latLong = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
        double lat = latLong.getDouble(0);
        double lon = latLong.getDouble(1);
        coordinates.add(new LatLng(lat, lon));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

System.err.println(Arrays.toString(coordinates.toArray()));

for (LatLng latLng : coordinates) {
    //use the coordinates.
}
```

Comment: I'm getting output like this lat lan : lat/lng: (13.0,77.0)

Comment: this is not Working

Comment: @Robot what type of output are you expecting?

Comment: [lat/lng: (13.042027380474938,77.61307530105115), lat/lng: (13.042088133203173,77.61339481920004), lat/lng: (13.041947030069515,77.6134082302451), lat/lng: (13.041881377889627,77.61312458664179)] like this

Comment: see I'm not getting the values in perfect way

Comment: [lat/lng: (13.0,77.0), lat/lng: (13.0,77.0), lat/lng: (13.0,77.0), lat/lng: (13.0,77.0)]

Comment: it is coming like this

Comment: @Robot sorry my bad, I used getLong instead of getDouble. Check the edited answer.

Comment: @NabinBhandari  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61206574/how-to-draw-polygon-using-string-array-of-latlng-in-google-map   can you help me :(

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a bunch of splits and replaceAlls to divide it up and then use the LatLan constructor in a foreach loop.

```
String latlng = "[[13.041695199971244, 77.61311285197735], [13.042000923637021, 77.61313531547785], [13.041830750574812, 77.61335827410221], [13.041507062142946, 77.61269208043814]]";

String[] latlngParts = latlng.split("\\], \\[");

for (String ll: latlngParts) {
    String llReplaced = ll.replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "");
    String[] llReplacedParts = llReplaced.split(", ");

    LatLng latlngObj = new LatLng(llReplacedParts[0], llReplacedParts[1]);

    // Then add latlngObj to some collection of LatLng objects
}
```

Comment: In string.split("] , ["); what is string

Comment: My bad, fixed the typos

Comment: Oh you have to escape those characters, like this `split("\\], \\[")`

Answer (score 1):

```
private  void doConvertToLatLan(){
        String latlan = "[[13.041695199971244, 77.61311285197735], [13.042000923637021, 77.61313531547785], [13.041830750574812, 77.61335827410221], [13.041507062142946, 77.61269208043814]]";
        latlan = latlan.replace("[[","[");
        latlan = latlan.replace("]]","]");
        latlan = latlan.replace("[","");
        latlan = latlan.replace("],","@");
        String[] latlanDParts = latlan.split("@");
        ArrayList<LatLan> data = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String value: latlanDParts) {
            String[] llReplacedParts = value.split(",");
            data.add(new LatLan(llReplacedParts[0], llReplacedParts[1]));
        }
        Log.d("Data",data.toString());
    }

    private class LatLan{
        private String lat,lan;

        public LatLan(String lat, String lan) {
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lan = lan;
        }

        public String getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(String lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public String getLan() {
            return lan;
        }

        public void setLan(String lan) {
            this.lan = lan;
        }
    };
```

I hope this will helpful!